# How do I access sinatra settings in custom extension specs?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, sinatra

I have an email helper extension I have written for my application.  I use settings I have defined on the application like so:

```
set :mailgun_options, JSON.parse(File.open('config/mailer.json').read)[ENV['RACK_ENV']]
```

which reads configuration settings from a json file into the global Sinatra settings.

I then have my email helper which references these settings to create connections and what not.

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'faraday'

module Sinatra
    module EmailHelper
        def connect opts={}
            connection =  Faraday.new(:url => settings.mailgun_options['mailgun_url']) do |faraday|
                if settings.mailgun_options['test']
                    faraday.adapter :test do |stubs|
                        stubs.post(settings.mailgun_options['domain'] + '/messages') {[ 200, {}, 'success' ]}
                    end
                else
                    faraday.request :url_encoded
                    faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
                end
            end

            connection.basic_auth('api', settings.mailgun_options['key'])
            return connection
        end

        def send_email params={}
            connect.post((settings.mailgun_options['domain'] + '/messages'), params)
        end

        def send_password_reset_email email
            template = File.open( File.expand_path( '../../helpers/email_helper/templates/password_reset.erb', __FILE__ ), 'r' ).read

            send_email({
                :from => 'REscour <noreply@' + settings.mailgun_options['domain'] + '>',
                :to => email,
                :subject => 'REscour.com Password Reset',
                :text => ERB.new(template).result(binding)
            })
        end
    end
end
```

So, when I am trying to write my specs to test the "connect" method, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `settings' for #<Class:0x007faaf9c9bd18>
```

My spec code is as follows:

```
module Sinatra
    describe EmailHelper
        let(:dummy_class) { Class.new { extend EmailHelper } }

        it 'should connect to mailgun\'s api' do
            app.set :mailgun_options, ::JSON.parse(File.open('config/mailer.json').read)['test']
            puts dummy_class.connect
        end
    end
end
```

I'm not sure how to interact with the global Sinatra settings from my specs to have the local "settings" variable be defined during execution of the helper code.

I could have the architecture of my application wrong here for all I know.  Does anyone have any experience in writing Sinatra extensions using the global settings and write specs for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec you've written seems to want to be a unit test, because you've not [run the extension the way it would be used in an app](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions-wild.html). In the specs, try something like:

```
describe "connect" do
  let(:app) { Sinatra.new do
                helpers Sinatra::EmailHelper

                configure do
                  :mailgun_options, ::JSON.parse(File.open('config/mailer.json')
                end

                get "/" do
                  connect
                end
              end
            }
   # now write specs for the `connect` helper
 end
```

Using an anonymous class (`Sinatra.new do`…) lets you quickly set up an app that's convenient for a small test, but there are other ways too.

In the extension, you need to add:

```
helpers EmailHelper
```

as per [the example in the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html#extending-the-request-context-with-sinatrahelpers).

Comment: I have added helpers EmailHelper to my helper, and I have rewritten the spec in accordance to what you've show.  But now I am getting undefined method `connect' for #<Class:0x007f96391d87c0>.  I am trying to call the method as app.connect from the 'it' blocks in my tests.  I cannot seem to get this straightened out

Comment: I did some digging and found out that the connect method is unbound.  Does this make sense of the situation?

Comment: @SpencerApplegate Helpers aren't available as instance methods on the app instance, so that won't work. When I say it looks like a unit test, there's testing the helper, and there's testing the route that uses the helper. If you're going to unit test *just* the helper, then don't set up an instance of the app at all and just use the helper in a spec as a normal method (if there are no Sinatra specific parts). Otherwise, write a spec for a route that users the helper, which is generally the best place to start IMO. See http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html for examples of testing routes.